# Issues parsing code using stringstream

Tags: c++, parsing, token, stringstream

My code currently parse a user input string called `aLine` into different tokens. Currently if I feed I input `x = "Foo" .add. "Bar"` The tokens are parsed as `|x| |=| |"Foo"| |.add.| |"Bar"|` which is perfect. However if I try and do the following `x = "Foo and" .add. "Bar"` it only parses until `|"Foo and Bar"|` and then the code goes into an infinite loop. Why is this happening?

```
 void splitLine(string aLine) {

    stringstream ss(aLine);
    string stringToken, outp;
    char delim = ' ';

    while (getline(ss, stringToken, delim)) { // Break line into tokens and store them in rTokenBag

        if (stringToken[0] == '"' && stringToken[stringToken.size() - 1] != '"' ) {
            string torzen;

            getline(ss, torzen, '"' );

            stringToken += ' ' + torzen + '"';
        }
        Token t(readToken(stringToken)); // assing value of stringToken parsed to t, this labes invalid tokens

        R_Tokens.push_back(t);
    }  
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Do you mean it's only parsing until `|"Foo and"|`? I don't see anything wrong with the code you are showing, except that there is no error check on the second read. Can your issue be inside `readToken` perhaps?

Comment: @super Yeah, I debugged using breakpoints and this is what happens: the code parses a string with a space no problem, say "Foo and", sends it as stringToken to readToken and no problem, but right after that the next pass stringToken, the string variable inside the while loop, is empty. and gets to readLine empty

Comment: @John Ah, ok. I see what the problem is, posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
getline(ss, torzen, '"' );

stringToken += ' ' + torzen + '"';
```

your getline will read up to the next delimiter, in this case `"`. That means after this exrtaction what's left of the string `[x = "Foo and" .add. "Bar"]` is `[ .add. "Bar"]`, notice the blank space at the start. Since you specified `"` as delimiter the space was not consumed.

This mean next time you call `getline(ss, stringToken, delim)` it will find a `' '` as the first character and immediately stop.

If you instead of changing the delimiter, and manually append a `"` just do a `getline` with space as delimiter again.

```
getline(ss, torzen, delim); // space as delimiter again

stringToken += ' ' + torzen; // torzen = and" so no need to add the "
```

Now your next iteration should work as intended and get `.add.`

**-- Edit --**

I just realized that you change delimiter since you want to read the whole string even if there are more then one space in it.

In that case you just need to dump the space after your operation, so you could do

```
getline(ss, torzen, '"' );

stringToken += ' ' + torzen + '"';
char dump;
ss >> dump;
```

Stick with what you already had, but make sure you consume the space after before you let the loop continue.